# Как найти два min значения в массиве случайных чисел?

Tags: массивы, ios, swift

Необходимо найти два min значения в массиве случайных числе. 
Код написан под **swift**.

```
var list = [Int] ()
var n: Int = 8

for i in 1...n
{
   let list = Int(arc4random_uniform(70))
   print (list)
}

func getMin1Min2(numbers:Int...) -> (min1:Int, min2:Int)
{
var min1 = numbers[0]
var min2 = numbers[0]

for number in numbers
{
if number < min1 {min1 = number}
```

Дальше попытка **найти 2-ое минимальное значение, но увы** ...

```
if number > min1
        {if number < min2
            {min2 = number}
        }
}
return (min1, min2)
}
```

**завершаться задача должна поиском двух мин. значений в рандомном массиве, но увы** не знаю как использовать созданный массив и функцию ...

```
var value = getMin1Min2 (list)
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала, Вы не заполняете массив. Вот создаете массив:

```
let n = 8
var arr = [Int]()
for _ in 0..<n {
    arr.append(Int(arc4random_uniform(70)))
}
print(arr)
```

Далее ищете 2 минимальных элемента в массиве, предлагаю просто отсортировать массив по возрастанию и возвращать первые 2 элемента:

```
func getMin1Min2(numbers:[Int]) -> (min1:Int, min2:Int){
    let sortedNumbers = numbers.sort({$0 < $1})
    return sortedNumbers.count > 1 ? (sortedNumbers[0], sortedNumbers[1]) : (sortedNumbers[0], sortedNumbers[0])
}
```

И проверка:

```
print(getMin1Min2(arr))
```

Answer (score -1):

Вариант 1: сделай копию массива, найди в нем минимум и удали его. Потом найди минимум еще раз.
Для не очень больших массивов подойдет.

Вариант 2: находишь первый минимум (запоминаешь его индекс).
Еще раз ищешь минимум в массиве, но уже *не сравниваешь* элемент с найденным индексом.

```
var myMin = MAX_INT
for i in 0..myArray.count {
    if (myArray[i] < myMin && i != indexOfFirstMin ){
        myMin = myArray[i]
    }
}
```